# Migrate AR experience on Microsoft surface 9 pro

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

We want to migrate an Unity AR Foundation (ARCore) app to Windows (UWP) on a Microsoft Surface pro 9.
The result is very strange:

1. We need to scan almost one thing (like Image target) else the Unity camera don't move;
2. Even if the tablet is on a desk, holograms are shaking.
   It's look like it use vision only instead vision + internal IMU.

Is there someone use Vuforia with a Microsoft surface? if yes, which one and is it working well?
Is there any chance that's work better on a Surface Pro 8 like this ref is on recommended devices list?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Vuforia should work better on the Surface Pro 8 than on the 9 since the first is on the list of supported devices (see here https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/recommended-devices). If you have a good use case for using the Pro 9 you can ask to add support by filing a ticket in the issue repo here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we have used the surface pro 9 because it's the latest version of this product and someone lent us one for our testing.
Before buying (this time) an other version, we want some feedback from users.

Comment: You should be aware that tracking performance on UWP devices is not on par with iOS and Android devices. On iOS and Android Vuforia uses as Device Tracker ARKit and ARCore respectively, which are highly integrated tracking algorithms. On UWP Surface tablets Vuforia deploys its own Vision + IMU tracker (as mentioned here https://library.vuforia.com/environments/vuforia-fusion). However the quality of the IMU information provided by the OS is somewhat lacking and this has an impact on tracking. For this reasons some Vuforia features (e.g., AreaTargets) are not supported on UWP tablets.

Comment: We already use the "VuforiaRuntimeUtilities.GetActiveFusionProvider()" to get which provider is currently used by Vuforia and we get VISION_ONLY. That suprised us because we are thinking that Vuforia could use the internal sensor to improve tracking. But we never arrived to get SENSOR_FUSION as provider despite try. And we think that our problems come from here.

Comment: Not all UWP devices support the SENSOR_FUSION provider. Only those on the recommended device list. To make the list the device has to be calibrated by someone in the Vuforia team. This has not happened for the Surface Pro 9. As I mentioned in my answer you can file a request on the GitHub repo.

Comment: First : the link to the github [link](https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/60) and this discussion confirm that the Microsoft surface Pro 9 (SP9) isn't calibrated by Vuforia. So the SENSOR_FUSION isn't available.
Second : We bought a SP8 and the result is clearly better, surely due to the SENSOR_FUSION provider enabled. We will continue our test with this version and follow the update about the compatible device list.
Thanks to @emay for his answers